# Does using the radio alert enemies to my presence?

Tags: fallout-4

Whenever I wander the Wasteland, I enjoy sneaking around with my weapon in-hand and my pip-boy radio on. I was curious though, does using radio alert enemies to my presence? I assume the pip-boy blasts the radio through its speakers at full volume.

Right now, my sneaking ability is pretty terrible, so the slightest movement lets all enemies within a 20 mile radius know of my whereabouts. That being said, I cannot determine whether or not the radio plays a factor.

Comment: I know using the light decreases your sneak ability... so probably.

Comment: I managed to sneak a grenade into a raider's pocket while my radio was running and my char isn't stealth-focused at all, so I'd say "no".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**As confirmed on [the Steam Forums](https://steamcommunity.com/app/377160/discussions/0/496881136901905961/), using the radio does not appear to impact on your ability to sneak.**

I have personally noticed what I perceive to be attention to my radio, however, not any more then I noticed in Fallout 3 and New Vegas. Double checking my sources for the purpose of this question, it appears that the radio did not directly effect sneak in [Fallout 3](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/939933-fallout-3/55173221) nor [New Vegas](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/959557-fallout-new-vegas/57130947).

Coomie makes a good point, regarding the fact that using the light definitely does decrease your chances of sneaking. However, keep in mind that the light has a hotkey to turn on and off, where as the radio does not. If radio decreased your chance of sneaking, you would have to manually turn it off before a perceived encounter, and bother to turn it back on again, afterwards. The radio also mostly adds atmosphere to the game, compared to the light, which serves to suit a specific function.

Comment: will definitely test this out more, and report back if I have anything to add.

Comment: Based on what I have seen the Steam Forum is correct... you could probably just say for roll playing sake that the character has earbuds or some crazy high tech version of them in his ears that you just can't see. For those who desire explanations to little oversights like that because some people are like that.

Comment: @Nightmare. It's funny how some people need an explanation for every little detail, but they never bother asking themselves why their character never sleeps, eats, drinks, or visits the toilet. It boggles my mind.

Comment: @Nolonar I don't know about your character; mine regularly sleeps, eats, drinks, _and_ visits the toilet (in his pants every time he sees a giant cockroach!).

Comment: @UnknownZombie Deathclaws and Yao Guai.  I got my new anti-animal sniper rifle, chambered for .50 cal, put a new receiver on it to make it the second most powerful weapon in my inventory (second only to my Missile Launcher), saw a "bear", lined up a headshot....  and barely moved the thing's health bar.  VATS, queue three headshots, first one's a critical, no misses....  still over 90% health.  And here comes a second one.  I left a brown streak from Tenpines to Walden Lake.