# Does an active radio aid stealth in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

To be clear:

- I am **not** asking about listening to the radio on the Pip-Boy.
- I am **also not** asking about the HAM radios.
- *I am* asking about stationary radios, already activated, found throughout the wasteland, and whether or not they affect an enemy's ability to detect the sole survivor. Another way of asking might be, "Do non-Pip-Boy radios distract enemies?" or "Do regular radios hinder enemy perception?"

Checking out [Carl's Fallout 4 Guide](https://www.carls-fallout-4-guide.com/sneaking.php), the entry regarding noise says:

> Like above, gunshots without silencers/suppressors will make a lot of noise, and alert others to your presence.

As a test, I have both shot into the ground and shot vertically into the sky, both alerting enemies the same. This suggests that gunshots affect the detection mechanic auditorily, not as a result of movement or item collision (bullet impacting the ground; bullet traveling through the air).

Further down, Carl notes:

> All of these contribute based on the Perception of the enemy you're sneaking up on. They may have better hearing and vision, or even sense of smell as with the Wasteland's wildlife. Certain foes have horrible perception, like Ghouls. Others, like Deathclaws - and even worse - Yao Guai, have very high perception. Human opponents that you encounter when your level rises - the harder ones - will have higher perception than a basic raider. Their senses are generally not as in tune as that of beasts, but they tend to be more intelligent and patrol.

Clearly, noise is experienced by enemies (or at least the appearance of such is given). While these are helpful insights, Carl makes no mention of stationary radios. Similarly, the [Fandom page](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Radio_(Fallout_4)) for these radios was also vacant of relevant information.

[This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/243753/does-using-the-radio-alert-enemies-to-my-presence/243756#243756) asks whether using the Pip-Boy radio alerts enemies to the sole survivor's presence. The accepted answer and at least one comment, as well as personal experience, all indicate that the inhabitants of the wasteland are oblivious to the sole survivor's Pip-Boy radio.

My wondering in regard to this, though, is whether this is a *localized* immunity to detection or a universal phenomenon applied to all radios. If it is universal, then great - question answered (*no, an active radio does not aid stealth*). If it is not, then the question remains.

[This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/244805/what-does-affect-how-fast-you-are-spotted-by-enemies/244812#244812) asks what affects how fast the sole survivor is spotted by enemies. Though the accepted answer here also touches on enemy perception and loud weapons, as well as noting the lack of effect by the Pip-Boy, the answer does not elaborate any further than already discussed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the very best of my knowledge (based on having played it routinely since it came out), noise is not modeled realistically in fallout 4.

Instead, you have a radius in which you can be heard and identified as an enemy.
This radius is governed by whether you're sneaking or walking, whether you're sprinting or even moving.

It isn't affected by ambient objects like generators or radios, and indeed, the sound can pass through walls as well.

Interestingly, it's apparently confirmed that your pipboy radio doesn't affect your ability to sneak at all. Apparently the Sole Survivor has wireless earbuds for their radio and holotape playbacks.

Comment: The others are a few exceptions  about noise coming exclusively from your character. Other NPCs can create noise, distract enemies, and can be spotted while they’re sneaking. Likewise grenade and bullet impacts can be used to lure enemies away from your location

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the game also mentions that noise is affected by the surface you walk on (e.g. wet surfaces are noisier), as well as the weight of your equipment.